# Can you use the watch window in Visual Studio 2010 while debugging remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I'm attempting to remotely debug an application. I can connect to it without an issue but as I step through the code I can not see the values of the variables the way I do when debugging locally.

When I try to evaluate a variable in the watch window I get the message "internal error in the expression evaluator". Do I need to do anything different to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug that affects Visual Studio 2012 when you remote debug an application compiled for .NET 3.5 or previous versions.

See [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764708/debugging-on-remote-server-with-vs2012-fails-and-2010-works-same-configurations-error-internal-error-in-the-expression-evaluator) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As described in Microsoft blog by link **Luca** in previous post you need perform these steps to fix this:

1. Install "Visual Studio 2012 Update 2"
2. Take from GAC "Microsoft.VisualStudio.vil.dll" vesion=11.0.0.0 on machine where you installed update
3. Copy assembly from prev. step to GAC on remote machine which you want debug
4. Optionally you can update remote debug tools on remote machine by "Update 2"

After that watch window should work correctly!

Comment: This is an excellent, succinct answer. It should be obvious, but some may need to enable copying from the GAC as described here: http://code-journey.com/2009/how-to-copy-dll-files-out-of-gac-windows-assembly-using-explorer-or-command-line/

Comment: I would say "step 4" should be "step 1". Generically, make sure that your remote debugger is the same version as your development IDE.